# Boundary value question

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations

Please don’t make fun… I’m just rusty, but I’ve forgotten how some basic conceptual rules apply, and I’m hoping for a straightforward answer. Take a simple example: $y'(x) = 2x$. The integral is obviously $y(x) = x^2 + C$, and we constrain $y$: maybe $y(0) = 0$, so $C = 0$, and $y(x) = x^2$.

But I’m doing an equation of the form $(d/dt) \Psi(x,t) = (d^2/dx^2) \Psi(x,t)$. What is the rule on the boundary conditions I need? I believe I need $\Psi(x,0) = a$, $\Psi(b,0) = c$, $\Psi'(b, t) = c$. Three boundary conditions, one per derivitave. Again, please don’t make too much fun… I’m getting old. But I believe every rate of change requires a b.c., correct? Thus, a double derivative w.r.t. $t$ on the left = a double derivative w.r.t. $x$ on the right requires four (4) b.c.’s: one for left, one for left derivative, one for right, and one for right derivative. Is that silly question correct? Thus, Schrodinger’s eqn., a single time derivative equals a laplacian in space (double derivative) requires three (3) b.c.’s to be fully constrained… Is that right?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just so you know, we're not here to make fun of anyone, we're here to help people with mathematics questions provided they have made an attempt to understand the work themselves. So you don't need to worry about that and your question would be better if those statements were omitted and just focused on what the issue is.

Comment: As to your question, it seems you are asking about the number of necessary boundary conditions (those in space) and initial conditions (those in time). As a rule of thumb, especially for the simpler PDEs (heat equation, wave equation, Laplace equation), you need a boundary condition for each spatial derivative (i.e $2$ as your equation is $\partial_{x}^{2}$) and one initial condition for each time derivative (i.e $1$ as your equation is $\partial_{t}$), though this does not always hold.

Comment: What is the interval in $x$ on which you are working? You need endpoint conditions at the endpoints of the interval; typically, those endpoint conditions would be fixed temperature, fixed flux, or a robin type of condition. And you'll usually specify a fixed temperature distribution at $t=0$ on the interval of interest. It is possible to allow these conditions to vary with time as well.